# JavaScript Confirm Box in PHP tag Keeps returning TRUE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, confirm

I'm trying to add javascript code inside php tags to process when a button is pressed it should confirm if the user actually wants to delete the image.

My issue is that once the Confirm box is shown - it returns true for both 'cancel' and 'ok' - it executes code either way to delete image from database.

Would anyone be able to provide any advice?

```
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
    $imgId = $_POST['imgId'];

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var h = "Are you sure you to delete Image ID: '.$imgId.'";

        if (!confirm(h)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {' .
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM images WHERE img_id='$imgId';") . '
        }

    </script>';
}
```

Comment: You can't put php function calls inside javascript.  You have to trigger the DELETE query by sending a http request to the server (ajax possibly).

Comment: It works fine for me. I get true and false.

Comment: @bub - Thats for the first confirm - which was used as a test - the second confirm always deletes the image and executes the query

Comment: I did mention - i said it executes the query

Comment: You need something like:  `?><script type="text/javascript"> var img = "<?PHP echo $imgId; ?>";
        var h = "Are you sure you to delete Image ID: "+img;

        if (confirm(h)) {
            $.post("delete.php",{"imgId":img});
        }
    </script>` - which seems to be silly since your are seemingly returning from a submission anyway

Comment: PHP by nature is a Server Side Language, anything you do in PHP WILL be executed before the website is displayed. This is where your issue lies, like @James said, you can't put PHP function calls in javascript like this... You'll have to use Ajax or a suitable replacement

Answer (score 1):

As somebody recommended, the best way in this case is to use JS (in this case i am going for jQuery) and make the php call in its own php file. Here you have a short snippet of html :

```
<a href="#" class="js-removeImg" data-image="10">Remove</a>
```

The data-image value (10) will be taken from php so you have to exaclty know what image are you removing. I usually like to add a "js-" prefix for the classes which will be linked inside any javascript trigger js-removeImg to separate the style and the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('.js-removeImg').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // Disables default click's behaviour

      var $this = $(this);  // Cache current jQuery element

      var imgID = $this.data('image');
      // ^ Stores the image id we want to handle
      // The value comes from PHP

      var deleteUrl = "deleteImg.php";
      // ^ A php file where the "delete" query will be available
      // As parameter it should accept the image id: $_REQUEST['imageID']
      // imageID should be exactly the same with the one inside date object from below

      var string = "Are you sure you want to delete the image with the id __IMGID__ ?";
      // ^Stores the string we want to alert in a nicer way, easy to edit in future      

      var confirm = window.confirm( string.replace('__IMGID__', imgID) );

      // User clicked "ok"
      if (confirm) {
        // So we are going to tell this to the server (php file)
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url : deleteUrl,
          data : {
            imageID: imgID
          },
          success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // Handle the data according to the answer received from PHP file
            // E.g : shown an alert which say that is done or not etc
          }
        });
      } else {
        // User clicked false
      }

  })
});
```

Above is the jQuery code that helps you to achieve your task. I think the comments are clearly enough.

Otherwise please let me know if something went wrong.